# TypeScript module testing with Jasmine

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-node

I have the following structure :
src folder with file1.ts
spec folder(same level as src - siblings) with file1.spec.ts
I try to run typescript Jasmine tests
file1.ts looks like this :

```
export module moduleName {
  export class className {
    public doSomething(a: string): string {
      return a;
    }
  }
}
```

file1.spec.ts looks like this :

```
const aliasFile = require('../src/file1');

describe("tests", function () {

  let f;

  beforeEach(function () {
    f = new aliasFile.className();
  });

  it("should run", function () {
    const result = f.doSomething('aaa');
    expect(result).toEqual('aaa');
  });
});
```

when I ran this test I get this result :

1. tests should run

- TypeError: aliasFile.className is not a constructor
- TypeError: Cannot read property 'doSomething' of undefined

what is the proper way to define the test?

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing `require` method with aliased `import` keyword like this:

```
import { moduleName as aliasFile } from './file1';

describe("tests", function () {

  let f: aliasFile.className;

  beforeEach(function () {
    f = new aliasFile.className();
  });
  it("should run", function () {
    const result = f.doSomething('aaa');
    expect(result).toEqual('aaa');

  });
});
```